# Encountered a Error When execute spark program by using python on pycharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I writed a python file named Wordcount.py on PyCharm.
This is the content of  Wordounct.py

```
import sys,os from pyspark import SparkContext  
sc = SparkContext()
myrdd = sc.textFile("passwd") 
myrdd.count()
```

When I run it ,i encounted a ERROR that display on console

The following is ERROR INFO

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /home/plters/PycharmProjects/Spark21/Wordcount.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/plters/PycharmProjects/Spark21/Wordcount.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
  File "/opt/spark2/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "/opt/spark2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 29, in <module>
    from py4j.protocol import Py4JError
ImportError: No module named 'py4j
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

looks like py4j module is missing, just install from the terminal

```
pip install py4j
```